# How to specify flow control parameters in PubSubTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using pull method to pull the messages out of my pubsub subscription as specified https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/#pull-methods, I see option to set max number of messages but don't see a way to specify the flow control params like `max-outstanding-element-count` and `max-outstanding-request-bytes` as in https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/#publishersubscriber-configuration

By debugging, i see 20MB is set to `max-outstanding-request-bytes` (screenshot) though it says DEFAULT_FLOW_CONTROL_SETTING should have 100MB https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/main/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java#L456

is there a way so that i can specify that value? I need to use PubSubTemplate with pull method!

Spring Boot: 2.3.5.RELEASE
spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub: 2.0.7

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you share us your code for us to replicate your scenario?